# Finding best result from mongodb databse

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am making a Recipe website project.

I have a collection named **Recipe** in my Mongodb atlas database.

In this **collection**, I have various **documents** of recipes.
This documents contains **name, timeToCook, proteinsContent, etc** fields.

It also contains **Keywords** field, which consists of array of words - which depicts the type of recipe.

Now, in this website, I want to add one functionality of Recommendation.

When user will open a particular recipe, the Keywords of this Recipe will go to backend. And I want to write a mongodb query in backend, which will find for recipes in collection which have more Keywords match as per the selected recipe.

Eg. If Recipe is **"RAISINS COOKIES"** and **Keywords** for it are-**Dessert,Snacks,Oven,Easy**.
So, I want to find the recipes in collections which will have Keywords which will match most of the Keywords given above.

I am using Mongodb and Nodejs.

Comment: It's a bit simplistic for a recommender system, but you could `"$sort"` the `"$size"` of the `"$setIntersection"` of the `"Keywords"`.

Comment: I am not good in mongodb query, can u plz help me with actual query code for it. Or suggest any documentation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simplistic recommender system that just examines the `"$size"` of the `"$setIntersection"` of the `"Keywords"`.

```js
db.Recipe.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "interSize": {
        "$size": {
          "$setIntersection": [
            "$Keywords",
            // your comparison Keywords go here
            ["Dessert", "Snacks", "Oven", "Easy"]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$sort": {"interSize": -1}},
  {"$limit": 5}
])
```

Try something similar on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0WgCB83rYNX).